# Tensorflow images classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I've been following the [official tensorflow guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification) for image classification because I want to code a steel scrap classifier script. After training the model with a set of various scrap photos I've tested the script and more or less it works as it should. Problems are actually popping out whenever I submit for test non steel images (like cars, flowers and animals), in fact as you can imagine the script should give almost 0% result but instead it actually gives ranging from 80% to 98% result and I can't really find a way to handle errors or non trained class classification. Do you have any tips or advanced guides in order to refine the script? Any help is very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Your classifier does not work well on other objects as steel because these images are out of distribution. A common solution to this problem is to use a two-stage model:

1. Steel vs. non-steel extraction: An easy way would be to just have a bool to indicate whether a picture contains steel or not. A more sophisticated approach would be to extract steel using bounding boxes, which can be done by finetuning a backbone such as YOLO.
2. Scrap vs. non-scrap classifier: You already built this, so you're halfway done.

Comment: That's good, I will follow the first step and see what I can come up with, I'm pretty new to AI world so I'm discovering stuffs step by step. Thanks though